# corrupted image files after upload to remote ftp server with laravel

Tags: laravel, ftp

hello guys i'm stuck here trying to figure out why uploaded files are being stored corrupted on ftp server.

this is my input on blade

```
<input type="file" id="newmidias" name="midias[]" />
```

this is my array of image on controller after i send using ajax:
[my_array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vLX1.jpg)

here is how I store files to ftp:

ftp_folder is "midias/"

```
$file_name = 'file.jpg';
```

`Storage::disk('ftp')->put('midias/'.$file_name, $_FILES[26]["name"]);`

any help is appeciated. thanks!

Comment: Don't use `$_FILES` directly for uploads - you want to use `$request->file()`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: when i try: dd($request->file('midias')); on controller, I get NULL, on chrome console...

Comment: Does your `<form>` tag have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on it?

Comment: no, it does not!

Comment: That's probably your problem, then. That parameter is required on forms for uploads to work.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me as following code using `fopen` in 2nd parameter:

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put('midias/'.$file_name, fopen($_FILES[26]["name"]), 'r+');
```